# How to formulate $\min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert^2 dx$ over $f_n,\ldots,f_0$?

Tags: optimization

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $I = [0,1]$ and let $g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let further be >$P_n(I)$ be the set of polynomials $f$ with $\deg(f) \le n$ on $I$. Formulate the problem
>
> $$\min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert^2 dx $$
>
> as a quadratic minimisation problem over $f_n,\ldots,f_0$.

I do not understand how to start here. I see that we may rewrite the problem a bit

$$\min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert^2 dx = \min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert \sum_{i=0}^n f_ix^i-g(x) \rvert^2 dx$$

, but I do not understand what to do now. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the minimization problem $\min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert \sum_{i=0}^n f_ix^i-g(x) \rvert^2 dx$ is a function of the coefficients $f_i$ and not of $x$.

Second, $\int_0^1 (f(x)-g(x))^2 dx = \int_0^1 f^{2}(x)+g^{2}(x) - 2f(x)g(x) dx$. But since the $g^2(x)$ term isn't a function of $f_i$ we can ignore this term in the optimization, i.e., $\min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert^2 dx = \min_{f \in P_n(I)} \int_0^1 f^2(x) - 2f(x)g(x) dx$. The integral of $f^2(x)$ is easy to compute since it is the integral of a polynomial squared. Using integration by parts the integral of $f(x)g(x)$ equals,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx &= \left[f(x)g^{(-1)}(x)\right]^{1}_{0} - \int^{1}_{0} f^{(1)}(x)g^{(-1)}(x) dx
\end{align}
where $h^{(i)}$ is the $i$-th derivative of $h$ and $h^{(-i)}$ is the $i$-th antiderivative of $h$. Note that since $g$ is continuous we know that the integral exists [How to prove that continuous functions are Riemann-integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56393/697762) and we know that polynomials are differentiable and integrable. Additionally, the integral of a continuous function is also continuous [Is an integral always continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429769/697762). We can repeat this process again on remaining integral term i.e,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx &= \left[f(x)g^{(-1)}(x)\right]^{1}_{0} - \int^{1}_{0} f^{(1)}(x)g^{(-1)}(x) dx \\
&= \left[f(x)g^{(-1)}(x)\right]^{1}_{0} - \left[f^{(1)}(x)g^{(-2)}(x)\right]^{1}_{0} + \int^{1}_{0} f^{(2)}(x)g^{(-2)}(x) dx \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i\left[f^{(i)}(x)g^{(-i-1))}(x)\right]^{1}_{0}
\end{align}
The process ends after the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$ since $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$.

Third, the integral of $f^2(x)$ will be a quadratic in $f_i$ and the integral of the $f(x)g(x)$ term will be linear in $f_i$. Therefore, after computing the integral out you can write the problem as a quadratic minimization problem over $f_i$.